# XML deserialize to object. How to construct object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I would like to deserialize the following XML to and object class in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32"
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                           LanguageAndScriptCode="en"
                           xsi:schemaLocation="http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32 http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32/ern-main.xsd"
                           MessageSchemaVersionId="2010/ern-main/32">
<MessageHeader>
    <MessageThreadId>PADPID</MessageThreadId>
    <MessageId>PADPIDA</MessageId>
    <MessageSender>
      <PartyId>PADPIDA</PartyId>
      <PartyName>
        <FullName>Tes co</FullName>
      </PartyName>
    </MessageSender>
    <SentOnBehalfOf>
      <PartyId>PADPIDA</PartyId>
      <PartyName>
        <FullName>Bp</FullName>
      </PartyName>
    </SentOnBehalfOf>
    <MessageRecipient>
      <PartyId>PADPIDA</PartyId>
      <PartyName>
        <FullName>Testo</FullName>
      </PartyName>
    </MessageRecipient>
    <MessageCreatedDateTime>2012-10-31T19:26:05Z</MessageCreatedDateTime>
    <!-- Message type ern:NewReleaseMessage -->
    <!-- Message version 20110307 -->
    <!-- Generated using code version 2012102902 -->
  </MessageHeader>
 </ern:NewReleaseMessage>
```

Here is my code to potentially deserialize to an object called NewReleaseMessage:

```
  var xmlstream = new FileStream(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlfilepath"],FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
  var dcs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewReleaseMessage));
  var loadfile = (NewReleaseMessage)dcs.Deserialize(xmlstream);
  xmlstream.Close();
```

Can somoene please help me to created the class to deserialize the object to?

I have tried the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
//using System.Runtime.Serializa

namespace Ddexcoverter2
{
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName  = "NewReleaseMessage" , Namespace  = "http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32")]
    public class NewReleaseMessage
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public MessageHeader MessageHeader { get; set; }

    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MessageHeader
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string MessageThreadId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public string MessageId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement]
        public MessageSender Sender { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class MessageSender
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string PartyId { get; set; }

    }

}
```

The object NewReleaseMessage is null when I attempt to run the program.

I have a feeling that the object I am trying to deserialize to is not constructed properly.
Can someone please help me constructs the object?

Comment: There is no element Sender in XML. You have it in code. It should be MessageSender.

Comment: But there is a class call MessageSender. Does the Sender property has to be the same name?

Answer (score 0):

It is failing on LanguageAndScriptCode attribute.

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NewReleaseMessage));
 serializer.UnknownAttribute += serializer_UnknownAttribute;
 serializer.UnknownElement += serializer_UnknownElement;
 serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode;
 NewReleaseMessage message = (NewReleaseMessage)serializer.Deserialize(file);
 file.Close();
```

Set breakpoint in UnknownNode handler and see it for yourself.

Also, when I paste the xml (and add missing ern:NewReleaseMessage closing tag), VS is giving warning "The element 'NewReleaseMessage' in namespace 'http://ddex.net/xml/2010/ern-main/32' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'UpdateIndicator'.".

So I think you need to make XML valid against this XSD first.

Comment: So is this a namespace issue overall?

Comment: This is also the beginning of a much bigger xml file

Comment: There are many issues with this xml. Check XSD for required elements and modify xml accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Tomas. I spent 2 weeks on this . I am an intermediate level programmer. I did not quite get how to see failing LanguageAndScriptCode attribute. Thats  serializer.UnknownAttribute += serializer_UnknownAttribute;
 serializer.UnknownElement += serializer_UnknownElement;
 serializer.UnknownNode += serializer_UnknownNode; Can you please simplify

Comment: Sure. I didn't include handlers for clarity, thinking it was obvious. See available events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx where you can put your code and check for XML errors during serialization/deserialization. Then check XmlNodeEventArgs argument for info what went wrong.

Comment: I got it. I can see the event after adding the handlers. Thanks

Comment: The only problem is the stack trace from the exception doesnt show the name of the unknown nodes. Example:

Comment: I have only created a class for a small portion of the XML. Do I have to construct the entire class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the given XSD file to create the C# classes automatically. Therfore you can use the command line tool xsd.exe.

For more information about xsd.exe visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. The xsd tool is contained in the Windows SDK that can be downloaded here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/bb980924.aspx?wt.svl=more_downloads. If installed it can be found here: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\{version}\bin".

To deserialize you can use your existing code.